# "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous "error in Python 3.X /Panda

Tags: python-3.x

Code :

```
if pd.to_numeric(df.Close) - pd.to_numeric(df.Open) >= 1:   
  (df.Label) = 1 
else:
  (df.Label) = 0
```

getting an error->

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
Date     Open    High     Low      Close 
1-Jan-08 6136.75 6165.35  6109.85  6144.35 
2-Jan-08 6144.7  6197     6060.85  6179.4 
3-Jan-08 6184.25 6230.15  6126.4   6178.55 
4-Jan-08 6179.1  6300.05  6179.1   6274.3 
7-Jan-08 6271    6289.8   6193.35  6279.1 
8-Jan-08 6282.45 6357.1   6221.6   6287.85
```

Can somebody help whats wrong?

Expected output: A new column "Label" with Label=1 if close >open else Label=0

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output. Also provide complete error message.

Comment: Edit the question and add info, don't copy-paste it into comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
df.Label = np.where(pd.to_numeric(df.Close) - pd.to_numeric(df.Open), 1, 0)
```

or for your specific case:

```
df.Label = (pd.to_numeric(df.Close) - pd.to_numeric(df.Open)).astype(int)
```

The value `pd.to_numeric(df.Open) >= 1` is a `Serie` of `boolean` which does not make sense in an `if` statement. The idea is to do an `if else` elementwise, hence the `np.where` syntax.

Comment: Thankyou.It worked.Wonder why If statement was not working.

Comment: @Pracz, do not hesitate to accept the answer. I will edit the answer to explain why the `if else` could not work